# How to check if a GLXcontext is remote or local

Tags: unix, opengl, x11, openglcontext

I'm experiencing problems since I'm calling cuGLGetDevices() on an application which uses the glXGetCurrentContext (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetCurrentContext.xml) function to query an OpenGL context. The context must be local and not remote via ssh for my app to work properly.

Is there any way I can detect if the context is remote or local?

Comment: the GLX context is not a normal openGL context, be careful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [glXIsDirect](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXIsDirect.xml) function